# How do I add a comment to a Google Doc with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I was looking at the documentation and found no way to add a comment using Google Apps Script.

After scrolling a bit, I found out that the [`addComment()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#deprecated-methods_1) function was deprecated.

Is there currently any way to add a comment to a Google Doc using GAS (without using a deprecated script)?

Comment: Please clarify where are you trying to add the comment? Your question title suggest a Google Document, but your question body is for a Google Site. For sites there is a separate [class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/comment) now. So you would do a `var com = sitePage.getComments()` and then use that class methods with `com` Don't think there is that option for a google doc.

Comment: Correct, this is currently not possible for docs/spreadsheets

Comment: @Vytautas Thanks. Yeah, I was asking about Google Docs, but thank you for realizing my error and helping answer my question despite it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add comments using the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (That must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). In the Script Editor select Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enable it in the Google Developers Console.)

Once enabled you can create a comment using 
[Comments: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/insert).

Here's an example:

```
function myFunction(){
  var fileId = '{YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID}';
  var resource = {'content': 'Le comment'};

  Drive.Comments.insert(resource, fileId)
}
```

Then you can verify the comment in the Comments section of your doc:

[image]

Comment: I think the Advanced Drive Service is now called Drive API. Worked great!

Comment: @GuitarViking The **advanced services** in Apps Script let you connect to certain **public Google APIs** and offers some benefits like autocomplete on the editor, and Apps Script handles the authorization flow automatically. For example the **advanced Drive service** allows you to use the **Google Drive web API** (: